# IBM DB2 9.7 end of service?

Tags: db2

I'm trying to find the End of Service date for IBM DB2 9.7. I could only find some page that was from 2012, stating that it has not yet been announced. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can search on the IBM [Support Lifecycle](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycle/index.html) page for `DB2 9.7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you were probably [looking at](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21168270) is correct.  No End of Service date has been announced for DB2 9.7 yet.